# Forgetting WiFi Password from inside app using User GUI Request not Programmatically in Iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, wifi

Since forgetting WiFi Password cannot be done Programmatically in iOS without jailbreak,

Is it possible to list all stored WiFi passwords in iphone, list them inside an application (or using GUI Request System Menu Intent(dialog or something)) and let the user pick one of the wifis to Forget it (Remove it) from the device? **using GUI Request, not Programmatically**.

Is it possible to do that in SWIFT or Objective-C without jailbreaking the iphone?